# How can my app allocate more heap memory in Android 4.0? (Not enough memory for my app)

Tags: android, memory, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, barcode-scanner, ram

I'm desesperate with my app. I'm developing an app for a dedicated barcode scanner Android based device. It's like an old phone (CPU Cortex-A8 OMAP 1Ghz, 512MB RAM), with Android 4.0. I can't root the system, nor update it, i've talked with the manufacturer.

The problem is that can't finish a simple (JSON) login. It tries to allocate more memory, but it can't.

[image: Barcode device android, after 7 mins]

Here is the same activity and the same process in the same network, but in an LG G2 (it tooks about 5s doing the login and the sync, as expected)

[image: Same activity, on LG G2]

In the barcode scanner device, I removed or hibernated ALL of the apps I can, I've installed Zend Launcher (which has a very little memory footprint), but I'm out of ideas now. I've tried android:largeHeap on manifest, without success.

Somebody has an idea for me? Thanks in advance

PS: The app must run in that barcode scanner, working on LG G2 is only for test and comparative purposes.

EDIT: I don't care about other apps in background, because this device will basically use this app, and nothing else.

Comment: So you are getting OOM crashes?

Comment: @simekadam no, no crashes at all, app stuck at a progressbar screen, and never finishes

Comment: And are sure that it's a memory error than? Do you have any exceptions in logcat?

Comment: Pretty sure because in other devices works perfectly. Logcat has no exceptions, only GCs http://pastebin.com/FGME4zkj

Comment: I've tried in Genymotion Android 4.0 in a emulator with 2G RAM and there isn't any issue

Comment: The JVM has either enough memory for object allocation, or it fails with OOM.
But your error still can be device specific..Did you try setting some breakpoints,...?

Comment: ...how do you know that the app tries to "allocate more memory, but it can't".? If it happens OOM would occur.

Comment: No, there is no OOM errors. Of course, my problem can be device-specific. I try to set some breakpoints in the process, but debugger freezes all the time, it's in the HTTP request. I can confirm with a proxy that the petition is done, and the response is OK, but appears the callback can't be fired/started

Comment: Ok, debugger can be wobbly at times:) Try to add some logging calls to debug your code flow. I can't help you much without code, errors,..
I just don't think this could be a RAM issue, just because of what I wrote before.

Comment: @simekadam thank you a lot, I will try that. Makes a lot of sense that if app was going OOM, it would throw OOMException or some ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77807/discussion-between-webo80-and-simekadam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. The peaks on the memory was lead by a graphical resource in the loading screen, not an OOM. And the log-in proccess took tooo much.

Comment: So, then delete the question. It seems the result was something unrelated. There is a specific close reason for that.

Comment: OK, will do it just now

Comment: Typo in my comment [ninja-edited]